# Como pintar el color de fondo a un LinearLayout

Tags: android-layout

> No me coge todo el ancho, aunque tengo definido el ancho como 'match_parent'

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> En la preview de android studio lo pinta bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Este Layout forma parte del recycler view aqui va codigo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#303030"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerConexiones"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Podrias agregar el layout completo como texto? Y aclarar si este layout esta siendo incluido dentro de otro por ejemplo. Como prueba, ponoele un background amarillo al layout padre para ver cuales son sus fronteras.

Comment: En la preview de android studio me lo pinta bien, toda la pantalla completa, y en el emulador no. Puede ser el problema en el recyclerView, aunque acabo de comprobar y esta todo match parent, tengo un relativeLayout match parent y dentro el recyclerView match_parent.

Comment: Agrega el layout como texto a la pregunta por favor.